# using ref to view error

Tags: c#

I working now on firm that using ref in every function.
The reason, is to catch errors.
There example  :

```
//return true if the read is success
//otherwise writing to the error ,the problem 
bool ReadFile(ref string error)
```

**Question:**
How do you catching errors?
Using ref,exceptions or other way?

Comment: On a side note, there is a class-wide implementation of a similar pattern using the interface IDataErrorInfo.  It allows you to provide more sophisticated error reporting based on overall class state and there are built-in ways to integrate the output with the UI (particularly in WPF.)  I consider this a better choice for informative error reporting than a 'ref' error message for each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that exceptions are the most convenient, robust and natural way to provide an error handling mechanism. They are just so feature-rich comparing to error codes and other things. The main problem is to actually classify an abnormal situation like 'exceptional'. If the situation is not 'exceptional', than the above tactics is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous alternatives to using `ref string sError` on every function as an input but still being able to check for errors using a boolean comparison.

Here's one pattern I've used in the past: create an OperationError object that you return from method that can report error information. Better yet, make it implicitly convertible to `bool` to make it easier to test when you don't care about the message.

Here's an example:

```
public sealed class OperationError
{
    public bool IsError { get; private set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator bool( OperationError err )
    { 
        return IsError;
    }

    // returned to indicate success
    public static readonly OperationError Success = 
         new OperationError();

    private OperationError() {}

    public OperationError( string errorMessage )
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage ?? "Unknown error";           
    }
}

// here's a case that demonstrates the usage:
public OperationError SomeMethod()
{
    if( someError() )
       return new OperationError( "someError failed, oops!" );

    return OperationError.Success; // all is well...
}


// somewhere else in your code...
var result = SomeMethod();
if( result.IsError )
    Console.WriteLine( result.ErrorMessage );

// alternatively...use the implicit bool conversion...
if( !SomeMethod() )
    throw new ApplicationException( "Oh no!" );
```

Comment: I've done this same sort of thing many times in the past...but it never occurred to me to make it implicitly convertible to a bool! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an accepted pattern, in some cases. You can see it in methods like `int.TryParse(...)` and all the other `Try...` methods in the framework (although they implement it better IMO). But it shouldn't be used exclusively and instead of exceptions. Exceptions aren't perfect, but they offer much more flexibility and control than this. This is basically returning to the world of `HRESULTs` and `ints` to indicate error/success, and we got away from that style with good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use exceptions for exceptional circumstances (i.e. things that should never happen or that are outside your control).

You can use a return type (you are using a `bool`) to indicate whether an operation was successful or not.

Personally, I don't like `ref` parameters as they have very specific type constraints (i.e. not polymorphic - you *have* to use the type passed in) and assume side affects by the function they get passed in to.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the

```
bool ReadFile(ref string error)
```

in a try catch block and not use a ref string.  Try catch is the generally accepted way of catching and handling errors.

If you are using .net 4.0 and you are really against throwing exceptions you can use a Tuple too:

```
Tuple<bool, string>
```

so:

```
private Tuple<bool, string> ReadFile()
{
...
}
```

Comment: It depends, sometimes you are fine with an error occurring and just want to move on, such as in a tight loop. If you caught exceptions here, your loop would run noticeably slower.

Comment: Not necessarily, to get the exception message you already had to raise the exception which is the expensive part.  You aren't saving anything by not bubbling it up to the calling function.